# Are tetra- and pentanitrotoluene better explosives than TNT?

Tags: organic-chemistry, explosives

When reading about TNT (trinitrotoluene), I noticed that the aromatic ring has still 2 carbon atoms left for two more possible nitro groups ($\ce{−NO2}$), which would get you tetra- or pentanitrotoluene.

[image: Unsubstituted carbon atoms in TNT]

The amount of available oxygen in TNT is not enough for a complete oxidation to water and carbon dioxide, this is obvious when looking at a possible reaction:
$$\ce{2 C7H5N3O6 -> 3 N2 + \mathbf{5\,H_2} + 12 CO + \textbf{2 C}}$$
Thus tetra- and pentanitrotoluene should be better explosives than TNT, because they both provide more oxygen than TNT. Why they were never popular? Are they harder to fabricate than TNT, can you nitrify them from TNT? Are they maybe unstable?

Comment: The synthesis is probably neither feasible not effective enough. You'll get better bang for fewer bucks.

Comment: Pentanitrotoluen has been prepared https://patents.google.com/patent/US4451681A/en  You have to balance their explosive power against the difficulty of production and handling

Comment: Keep in mind that [octanitrocubane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octanitrocubane) would  have ideal stoichiometry but is *much* harder and more expensive to synthesize .. and ironically seems to have lower crystal density. Having talked to a few explosives chemists, there's a lot unknown (even beyond the "we're not talking" bits).

Comment: On more serious note, yes they're obviously unstable and I wonder why these guys^ bothered with patent.

Comment: @Mithoron, why are they unstable?

Comment: Read up on steric inhibition of resonance and you'll get some insight.